# Can I get control from page placed in a frame of another page?

Tags: asp.net, iframe, checkbox, repeater, content-pages

I am a desktop client developer. I now got to continue this project is ASP.NET with AJAX, so I am learning web development the hard way.

I need to get a list of all check boxes and their states from **repeater** control on **Summary.aspx** when user clicks button **CmdSave** on **ChoicePage.aspx**.

Can I subscribe to event CmdSave_Click() in **Summary.aspx** or is there some way to approach **Summary.aspx**'s repeater control from **ChoicePage.aspx**?

(MSDN talks about passing values from page to page in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx) article but this doesn't help me)

Here is the problem:
Page **ChoicePage.aspx** is included in Master AppMaster.master page. **ChoicePage** has Content tag which includes CmdSave and it's event handler **CmdSave_Click()** and it also includes **iframe** tag for displaying another page, **Summary.aspx**

On **Summary.aspx** I have repeater control which is bound to DataSource and relevant fields are of type bool represented by column of editable **check boxes**. Clicking these checkboxes mustn't cause Summary.aspx to refresh so I am not looking to handle (server-side) CheckedChanged event.

I am not sure if any code example would help here since this is more a concept question

```
function SetFrameStatus() {
        var v = hdCommand.value.toString().toLowerCase();
        hdCommand.value = "";

        var frms = (GetFrameAll("FrameSummary"));
        if (frms)
        { }
        else return;
        FrameSummary = frms[0];
        DivSummary = FrameSummary.parentNode;
        var FrameWindow = frms[1];
        var FrameDocument = frms[2];
        if (v == "showsummary") {
            FrameWindow.location.replace(SummaryPageName);
        }
 }

<asp:Content ID="ContentSummary" ContentPlaceHolderID="NoUpdateDiv" runat="server">
    <div id="DivMenu" class="Flat" style="overflow:visible; display:none;position:absolute;">
        <input type="button" id="CmdSave" value="Save" onclick="CmdSave_Click()" />
    </div>    
    <div id="DivSummary" style="position:absolute;margin:0px;padding:0px;display:none">
    <iframe title="Loading" id="FrameSummary" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" scrolling="auto"
        style="padding:0px; margin:0px;width:auto;" src="loading.htm?Redirect=Summary.aspx" frameborder="0" 
        onload="FrameSummary_Load()"
    ></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: In the end this is what solved my problem:

On ChoicePage.aspx in CmdSave_Click() function I called another function on Summary.aspx. This other function did __dopostback("Repeater", "") and on Render event in my code behind I itterate through Repeater. I am leaven question unanswered because I am sure there is a better way to do this. Happy coding everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this is what solved my problem:

On ChoicePage.aspx in `CmdSave_Click()` function I called another function on Summary.aspx.

This other function did `__dopostback("Repeater", "")` and on `Render event` in my code behind I iterate through a Repeater.

I am leaving this question unanswered because I am sure there is a better way to do this.